# how to use encrypted config file in Membership provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, asp.net-membership

I am using standard Login control of asp.net with Membership provider for authentication. My requirement is to encrypt config file or particular section of it and decrypt while using it. 
Problem is How should i encrypt Web.Config file or particular section so that my Membership provider will work properly. Or should I change something in Membership.
If anyone know how to do it Please let me know.
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to [Walkthrough: Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dtkwfdky%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I found the article to be very useful